# How to get this information when executing queries? (query time, lock time, rows sent and rows examined)

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm looking for this information when executing queries:

```
# Query_time: 11.639269  Lock_time: 0.000192 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined:
6509098
```

How can I get this from the command line?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637715/is-there-a-way-to-get-rows-examined-in-mysql-without-the-slow-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is the quite convoluted combination of

- `EXPLAIN ...`
- `SET profile=1;`,
- The actual `SELECT`
- `SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY <id>\G;`
- ...and then some manual calculations.

If someone can come up with a better method I'd very much welcome it (although the calculations could be done in a stored procedure of course).

Comment: Seems like when you activate the slow query log, this information is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I know where it's from. It's _only_ displayed in the slow query log for me, having it on the command line when running/testing queries I haven't seen it yet. One can calculate it, but it's not that user friendly (end setting long_query_time to something like 0.005 doesn't sit well with me).