# Is there any way to know how many rows where actually scanned in a sql? I don't mean using explain

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to know how many rows where actually scanned in a sql?

I don't mean using explain.

Comment: You mean you want to return a percentage of how many rows matched out of all records.. or can you explain more?

Comment: There is a feature called query logging in MySQL. I don't know whether this will give you the total row count a query scanned, though.

Comment: Isn't that what `EXPLAIN` is for? Why do you not want to use `EXPLAIN` or what is the problem with that?

Comment: This is part of the information that the profiler/performance_schema will collect, see e.g. [Is there a way to get rows_examined in MySQL without the slow log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1637715) and, since it is a bit dated, the current manuals.

Comment: @user3783243 As "Explain" for a sql, the result for scanned rows is not accurate, it's estimated. So I want to know the accurate number.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  OK I'll try

Comment: @Progman Using "EXPLAIN" scanned rows is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL introduces a new command [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-analyze) in version 8.0.18. Run

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE your_query
```

to see a detailed execution plan that was executed to run the query.